# Unable to import SyncOnSubscribe with RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

I am trying to use SyncOnSubscribe, but it is apparently not included in

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava 
compile group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.2.16'
```

I am starting to suspect that it was dropped between RxJava1 and RxJava2.  If that is the case, what is the RxJava2 alternative?  If it part of RxJava2, what do I need to include in build.gradle to be able to import it?

Comment: @akarnokd You probably know where SyncOnSubscribe is located, I'm hoping.  :-)

Comment: I was hoping you read the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#factory-methods) first.

Comment: lol Thanks for your reply.  And apologies for bothering you.  I honestly searched diligently before asking, but it was not even evident to me that SyncOnSubscribe was RxJava 1 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SyncOnSubscribe is RxJava 1 only.  For RxJava 2, use Flowable.generate or fromCallable.